# How did David come back to life for choosing dreams?

Tags: plot-explanation, vanilla-sky

In *Vanilla Sky* David commits suicide because he is suffering constant pain and depression following his disfigurement. So In the end David chooses to be awakened in this future. So my question is: How did David come back to life for choosing dreams?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a plot twist that you might have missed.

After the club night where David passes out on the street, he goes and signs a contract with the company Life Extension to be frozen after his death. That is revealed later ([full synopsis here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0259711/synopsis)) when:

> The Support Technician explains that the Lucid Dream was "spliced"
>   into his memories at the point where he passed out on the sidewalk
>   after his night out with Sofia and Brian.

So he committed suicide but that doesn't mean he permanently died - he would need to be alive to be kept in the cryogenic suspension. An emergency rescue team probably applied first aid procedures and brought him back to life before freezing him.